# Keeping matplotlib axis formatting for future plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I really think my google skills and matplotlib documentation readings skills are failing me...but I do not seem to be able to find an answer.

I am applying some formatting to some plots I am doing:

```
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('none')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('none')
ax.grid(True, 'major', 'y', color='#D3D3D3')
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=12, labelcolor='#545454')
```

I would like this formatting to be applied to any future plots I do as well.  Currently, as soon as I do a new plot, even of the same chart type and using the same data, the default formatting comes back.

I realise I can plot multiple charts in one figure, and I am doing this at times, but sometimes I only want to plot one chart at a time.

Is there a way to do this?  Or is copy and paste my only solution?

Thanks for your time,
Ian.

Comment: You can use [`rcParams`](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html).

Comment: Thank you muchly, @ImportanceOfBeingErnest -- exactly what I need.